# Update karateEnv within feature rather than cmd line or runner

Tags: karate

I was looking for a way to update the karate.env value for specific features, so that individual scenarios could be ran using the `Run>>` option above the respective scenario/feature.  During manual runtime with the karate plugin Run>> option, test do not appear to return the karate.env value even after setting the systemProperty value, the result still appears as null, although the update shows a success when reading the systemProperty directly.

Is there a way to update the karate.env variable at runtime?

I attempted to see if there was a PropertyPermission set on the systemProperty, but found none when trying to access it with karate.env within feature files.

Here is a sample feature and java call to verify
setkarateEnv.feature

```
Feature: Update Karate.env for local run with Run>> plugin option above individual scenario
  
  Background:    
    * def systemProperties = Java.type('commonutilhelpers.SystemProperties')

  Scenario: Set karate.env
    * def env = systemProperties.SetKarateEnv('dev')
    * print 'karate.env is now ', karate.env

    * def env = systemProperties.SetKarateEnv('uat')
    * print 'karate.env is now ', karate.env

    * def env = systemProperties.SetKarateEnv('qa')
    * print 'karate.env is now ', karate.properties['karate.env']
```

system properties java file

```
package commonutilhelpers;

public class SystemProperties {
    public static String systemPropertyValue(String propertyName) {
        String sysPropoertyValue = System.getProperty(propertyName);
        return sysPropoertyValue;
    }

    public static void SetKarateEnv(String environment) {
        System.setProperty("karate.env", environment);

        String verifiedEnvUpdated = systemPropertyValue("karate.env");
        System.out.println("verifiedEnvUpdated is " + verifiedEnvUpdated);
    }
}
```

The output [System.out.println] statements show the system property is updated, as expected; however, the same value is not reflected in the karate.env variable when printed within the feature file.

```
verifiedEnvUpdated is dev
22:07:30.476 [com.intuit.karate.Main.main()] INFO  com.intuit.karate - [print] karate.env is now  null 
22:07:30.476 [com.intuit.karate.Main.main()] DEBUG c.intuit.karate.core.ScenarioEngine - over-writing existing variable 'env' with new value: systemProperties.SetKarateEnv('uat')
verifiedEnvUpdated is uat
22:07:30.477 [com.intuit.karate.Main.main()] INFO  com.intuit.karate - [print] karate.env is now  null 
22:07:30.478 [com.intuit.karate.Main.main()] DEBUG c.intuit.karate.core.ScenarioEngine - over-writing existing variable 'env' with new value: systemProperties.SetKarateEnv('qa')
verifiedEnvUpdated is qa
22:07:30.480 [com.intuit.karate.Main.main()] INFO  com.intuit.karate - [print] karate.env is now  null
```

Answer (score 0):

You cannot change the `karate.env` during a test. This is a critical design decision.

Comment: Not looking to change during a test, but simply be able to execute a single scenario, outline or feature using the RUN>> command that the plugin offers.  Since ALL of our services require authentication, we currently have to set a tag for the individual test, and then run via cmd line or runner.  The other option is to allow testers to update the env set in the config (which is global to all teams) and could cause issues for everyone if not reset after their testing.

Comment: using a tag is not the best or only way to run one feature or scenario at a time. you can always pass the feature path (and `:<linenumber>`) as the last argument in the `karate.options` (or command-line) and dynamically run any combination that you want: https://github.com/karatelabs/karate#karateoptions - there are also plenty of options for you to do that "filtering" via a java helper. tags are for selecting (and un-selecting) test groups and env is for switching config